# how to use memory profiler in python in windows using IDLE

Tags: python

I want to analyze the space and time complexity for my code but for windows idle I am not getting how to use memory profiler ,I have installed that package but how to use it or we have some different way to implement it
I am not happy with the outcome of

```
    import time
    start_time = time.time()
    #code
    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

also Guppy is outdated so its not working 
I also want to know that which line of code is taking more time .
Please provide me links for how to use it or anything else

Answer (score 0):

First of all, memory profiler in python is used to calculate the space or memory your particular function is using. For using the memory profiler you have to import memory_profiler library and than use a decorator over the function you want to get the memory details.

For getting the time for your every step in your program you can use line profiler instead of using time function.

Here is an example code :`

```
from memory_profiler import profile

  @profile(precision=4)
  def f():
     a = [1] * (10 ** 2)
     b = [2] * (2 * 10 ** 7)
    for i in range(100):
       print i

       del b
       del a

 f()`
```